Is it possible to get Vim to recognize numbers with the format 1_000_000?
If for example I have the number 1_000_000, using 10<C-x> gives me -9_000_000 because Vim is only recognizing the 1 part as a valid integer. I'm aware that underscores aren't technically valid integers, but quite a number of languages use this format to make integers in code more readable. Is there a way(perhaps with nrformats, though I couldn't find anything), to make Vim decrement 1_000_000 to 999_990 if I run 10<C-x>?

If you don't get an answer here you can also try [vi.se].

There is no option for that. If you can't find a plugin that does what you want, then you will have to write your own wrapper around <C-x> and <C-a>.
